# What is AND-parallelism and OR-parallelism?

Tags: parallel-processing

I am currently reading somebody's thesis and I keep coming across the terms "AND-parallelism" and "OR-parallelism". A simple google search doesn't reveal a simple explanation. So what is "AND-parallelism" and "OR-parallelism" and how are they different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a logic programming context, when you have either a conjunction or a disjunction of goals, there's a potential to prove all the goals in parallel. In the case of a conjunction of goals, you talk about and-parallelism while for a disjunction of goals you talk about or-parallelism. And-parallelism is simple when all the goals are independent (i.e. the output of a goal is not used as input for another goal; there are however cases using accumulators being passed around where the goals can still be treated as independent). In other cases it quickly becomes tricky. As the name implies, in and-parallelism, all goals must be true for the conjunction to be true. For or-parallelism, it's enough for one of the goals to be true. This leads to a variant know as competitive or-parallelism where as soon as you prove one of the goals you can stop the search for a proof for the other goals.

Both independent or-parallelism and or-parallelism can be either implicit, i.e. the compiler recognizes the cases where proofs can be parallelized, or explicit. In the later case, it's the programmer, usually using language constructs, that tells the compiler which goals can be run in parallel. An example of an implementation of implicit or-parallelism is YapOr.

Both independent or-parallelism and (competitive) or-parallelism can be implemented using multi-threading. Logtalk supports it when using SWI-Prolog, XSB, or YAP s the Prolog back-end compilers. Several examples can be found on the Logtalk distribution for both independent or-parallelism and competitive or-parallelism. The SWI-Prolog distribution also includes a library provide similar functionality. Also related and interesting is the concept of logical engines found e.g. in Lean Prolog.

There is plenty of papers on this subject if you want to dig further. I hope I provided enough information to get you started if you want to understand and play with this concepts.

Answer (score 0):

The terms appear in the context of parallel evaluation of programs written in Prolog (logic languages in general).
You can find an explanation here:

http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~epontell/adventure/node12.html